# JPA TopLink Help!

Tags: jpa, named-parameters, named-query, toplink-essentials

Greetings,

As of now I had accomplished building a single-table JPA.
But when going to one-to-one or one-to-many. Things get complicated.
Especially when it comes to queries with parameters.

I always get an exception on a named-query

```
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [Subject.searchBySubjectCode: 
SELECT s FROM Subject s WHERE s.subjectcode = :subjectcode], line 1, column 33: 
unknown state or association field [subjectcode] of class [model.Subject].
```

How is this possible?
Yet I added both entities on the persistence.xml.
BTW, I'm using TopLink Essentials and implement the JPA on MVC Architecture.
In addition, when I re-open the form, this exception always returns then.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: <query> not found.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the problem again... Just used TypedQuery